# Подключение расширения XDEBUG

Tags: php

Везде пишут что под windows нужно подключать это расширение вот так:

```
zend_extension_ts="C:/PHP/ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll"
```

В phpinfo Thread Safety у меня enabled, поэтому на сколько я понимаю использование _ts вполне оправдана.

Но дело в том что расширение не подключается таким макаром, оно просто не появляется в phpinfo. Тем не менее если написать:

```
extension="C:/PHP/ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll"
zend_extension="C:/PHP/ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll"
```

То есть сначала врубаем его в php, затем в zend и оно появляется, и IDE даже устанавливает с ним соединение но отладка не работает, переменные не отображаются, работает только коннект с раширеним..

php 5.3.8 TS VC9

Apache 2.21

P.S. Причем в лого Zend надпись типа "powered by Xdebuge" не появляется.
Апач и пхп чистые и голые, на них ничего нету, почему же расширение не включается по простой одной команде:

```
zend_extension="C:/PHP/ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll"
```

Опытные phpэшеры, помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

у меня в настройках выставлено

```
; XDEBUG Extension

zend_extension = "D:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:/wamp/tmp"
```

если это поможет :)